# Cannot create a file with sudo in Apache web directory

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, sudo

Suddenly the following problem has happened:
I have an Apache web directory at /www. Everything was ok with the permissions, but at some point (I can't realize what caused it), I become unable to create any new files in this directory.

I have tried two methods:

1. Saving a new file from Sublime
2. running `sudo echo "" > newfile`.

But both methods failed. On the other hand I am able to create new files in my home directory (using both mentioned ways) and then to copy or move them to /www. What may be the issue and how to solve it?

Comment: What does `ls -l /` show for www ?

Comment: Does the `sudo echo` thing fail silently or return an error code/message?

Comment: `ls -l /` for www returns:  
drwxr-xr-x   8 root  wheel      272 19 Nov 23:58 www  
  
`sudo echo "" > newfile` returns:  
-bash: newfile: Permission denied

Comment: does newfile exist already? Can you do the full path sudo echo "" > /www/newfile

Comment: newfile doesn't exist (I am just new to Mac, but in general I know what I am doing). Running with the full path has the same effect. BTW `sudo mkdir newdir` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo echo "" > newfile` should never have worked, because sudo only applies to the echo command and not to the redirection. Try using `sudo touch newfile` or `echo "" | sudo tee newfile`.

Sublime Text doesn't seem to support creating new files to a directory you don't have write permission to. It does support authenticating as root when modifying an existing file though. See http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/27820-prompt-if-need-elevated-permission-to-save/.

Maybe you did have write permission to the directory earlier but something (like upgrading to 10.9) removed it.